# Why don't I see results of printfn called outside the main entrypoint (F#)

Tags: f#

I have a F# console application that calls functions in other modules to perform its work from the main function entrypoint. I have a series of `printfn` in these other functions to provide me with information on the running of the program.

When compiled in DEBUG mode, all the statements print to the console. However, when compiled in RELEASE mode the only statements that print to the console are those that are directly inside the main entrypoint function.

What can I do to print statements for info in these other modules?

A code example is provided below:

Program.fs

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  printfn "%s" "start"   // prints in RELEASE and DEBUG mode

  File1.Run

  printfn "%s" "end"     // prints in RELEASE and DEBUG mode
  System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
  0 // return an integer exit code
```

File1.fs

```
module File1

let Run = 
  let x = 1
  printfn "%d" x  // this won't print in RELEASE mode
```

Comment: It's hard to find out without any code sample provided

Comment: @Petr I have provided a small sample to illustrate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yep you are (kindof) right - it will not print as `Run` is an expression here and it seems the compiler is optimizing it away in release mode.

And why should it not? In a perfect (pure/referential transparent) world you have an expression of type `unit` that can only have a single value `()` ... and you don't even use or remember the value!

To be honest I don't know if this is a bug or a feature ;)

anyway this simple *trick* will help you and indeed you should not use an expression with effects in the way you did:

```
let Run () = 
  let x = 1
  printfn "%d" x

...

File1.Run ()
```

see - now it's a function and get's called at the right time and your output is back ;)

---

btw: if you are interested in this kind of stuff you an either use tools like Reflector (which I do not have at hand at the moment) or just use **IL DASM** (a tool VS should install anyway) - if you look at the compiled debug/release assemblies you will notice that nowhere something like this:

```
IL_001f:  call       class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit File1::get_Run()
```

can be found in the release version if you use the expression.

---

I played with it a bit and you have to get creative to make the compiler do this stuff:

For example

```
let reallyNeed v =
    if v = ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  printfn "%s" "start"   // prints in RELEASE and DEBUG mode

  File1.Run |> reallyNeed


  printfn "%s" "end"     // prints in RELEASE and DEBUG mode
  System.Console.ReadLine () |> ignore
  0 // return an integer exit code
```

works (it prints your `1`) - while

```
ignore File1.Run
```

or

```
let reallyNeed v = ignore v
```

don`t ;) - seems like you have to *actually* use the value somewhere :D

Comment: Part of it probably has to do with when module members are evaluated.  There are some rules around this that I don't remember offhand.

Comment: I think the compiler is stripping unused values - or so it seems but you might be right of course. As this seems to be borderline (I don't think the OPs intend was to use a value here) my opinion on it would be **feature** not bug - but in this case ... yeah